# Will progressive web apps run on Amazon Fire 7?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, kindle-fire

I have a kindle fire 7, Android 5.1.1 with the latest Chrome installed (v84).  I wrote a simple PWA (progressive web app) template, and also have tried some known sites that have progressive web apps, but I never get that install button to render in Chrome, meaning apparently the beforeinstallprompt even is never fired, although I know that the sites are valid PWA sites since they are installable in the desktop version of Chrome.

Is there an android or chrome setting that I can tweak to be able to install the PWA on the kindle fire?

Comment: were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: @user805981 No I wasn't, but I didn't try too hard.  I found a way to make my website run fullscreen on the Kindle without being a PWA

Comment: @draca - how did you manage to do that, please?

Comment: @Shaun  use the fullscreen api, for example   document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()  see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen